# Python NLTK named entity recognition depends by the (upper)case of first letter?

Tags: python-2.7, classification, nltk, text-classification

I am planning on using Python NLTK for academic research. In particular, I need a way of screening the Twitter users and tease out the ones who do not seem to be using a "real name" in their profile.

I am thinking about using the default NLTK's name-entity recognition to separate the Twitter users who use seemingly real name from those who aren't. Do you think it's worth the try? Or should I train the classifier by myself?

```
import nltk
import re
import time

##contentArray0 =['Health Alerts', "Kenna Hill"]

contentArray =['ICU nurse toronto']

##let the fun begin!##
def processLanguage():
    try:
        for item in contentArray:
            tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(item)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
            print tagged

            namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)
            ##namedEnt.draw()

            time.sleep(1)

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)


processLanguage()
```

Edit: I have done a bit of testing. It seems nltk recognizes a name entity primarily by whether or not the first letter of the word is capital? For example, "ICU Nurse Toronto" will be recognized with NNP while "ICU nurse toronto" will not. It seems overly-simplistic and not very useful for my purpose (twitter) since many Twitter users using real name could be using lower case while some commercial organization will be using capital first letter.

Comment: train a truecaser on proper text and then use the truecaser on twitter text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely train one yourself. The NLTK's NE recognizer is trained to recognize named entities embedded in full sentences. But don't just retrain the nltk's NE recognizer on new data; it is a "sequential classifier", meaning it takes into account the surrounding words and POS tags and the named-entity classification of the preceding words. Since you already have the usernames, these will not be useful or relevant for your purposes.

I suggest you train a regular classifier (e.g., Naive Bayes), feed it whatever custom features you think might be relevant, and ask it to decide "is this a real name". To train, you *must* have a training corpus that contains examples of names and examples of non-names. Ideally the corpus should consist of what you're trying to classify: twitter handles.

Re the question in your comment, don't use entire words as features: your classifier can only reason with features it knows about, so census names can't help you with novel names unless your features are about *parts* of the name. Usually the features represent the endings (last letter, final bigram, final trigram), but you can try other things too like length and of course capitalization. The NLTK chapter discusses the task of recognizing the gender of names, and gives many examples of suffix features.

The catch, in your case, is that you have multiple words. So your classifier needs to be told somehow if some words are recognized as names and some are not. Somehow you must define your features in a way that preserves this information. E.g., you could set the feature "known names" to have the values "None", "One", "Several", "All". (Note that the NLTK's implementation treats feature values as "categories": They are simply distinct values. You can use 3 and 4 as feature values, but as far as the classifier is concerned you might as well have used "green" and "elevator".)

And don't forget to add a "bias" feature with constant value (see the NLTK chapter).

Comment: Thanks, say I have a census data (with real names) to train, what would be the best way to train in order to take care of names in Twitter profiles that are not in the census data? For example, should I use the whole first name and last name as feature? And should I use negative example, like training with dictionary words to indicate what are NOT names?

Comment: Expanded my answer with the answers. You need a training corpus with both positive and negative examples. But really you have to read the NLTK chapter and come back with follow-up questions.

Comment: I have read the chapter a number of times before actually, and I have done a naive bayes classifier before. I think what is challenging is to find the right negative examples (non-names) and find out which features to extract that will consistently distinguish real names from other English words.

Comment: For negative example (non-names), where would be a good source? I have looked at the dictionary, but names occur in dictionary. Can the negative examples be all non-noun entries from English (Oxford) dictionary?

Comment: You'll definitely get best results if your corpus consists of usernames, categorized into person names and non-names. It's anybody's guess if you can get usable results by training on a random collection of non-name words; even if you subtract proper names from a dictionary (which is probably not that hard to do), what you're left is not suited for training a classifier since it looks nothing like a Twitter user name. Can you code a large enough corpus of twitter names by hand to use as training?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, and that's the reason why I am seeking existing named-entity classifier, or a reliable way to find positive and negative examples. I am one person doing the research and it's only part of my research. How many positive and negative sample (aka corpus) do you think I need to hand code? To estimate, say I can code 6 names in 1 min, working 8 hours a day, it will be 2880 names coded a day. So in 5 days it will be 14400 names.

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask me that. I'm going to guess that a week's worth of names will be plenty, but really I have no clue, it's your corpus and your research question-- what accuracy will you be happy with? How much time could you put in this? Code a few hundred names and use them to evaluate the performance of whatever you have put together so far. (I.e. use them for testing, not training!). Then take it from there.

Comment: I feel like there is a stronger way of figuring out name vs. non-name than bayes by using something like markov modelling on the pos tags or even with a dictionary and then performing Bayes or identifying potential names with Bayes and using an SVM/neural net to decide name or not based on given sentences. Organization also contain common words that may actually just be common words. Bayes would look for frequencies of the actual word. That could be a huge problem for people and organizations in some cases. This may help as well https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE.

Comment: @Andrew, your hunch is right: POS tags and sentence context are certainly relevant to NER. But Bayes classification need not be shallow bag-of-words classification: You are free to define POS-based and order-dependent features-- and in general, you should. However, *this question* is about classifying **twitter profile names** as names or non-names. There's no sentence structure, and nothing that could be POS-tagged with a general-purpose tagger.

Comment: PS. The NLTK provides numerous classifiers, and I didn't specifically endorse Bayes; usually it's a good idea to try different ML engines and see which one gives the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely have to train a classifier yourself. As an example, since you are working on names, you could have a look at this NLTK [chapter](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html). The simple Naive Bayes classifier that the chapter describes to test whether a name is a 'male' or 'female' gives a good insight into the kind of features. Also your question on asking what features, is more of a problem and domain specific question. Apart from the generic features that all Information Extraction researchers use, there might be other kinds of features as well. But again these are purely dependent on your data. Do go through that chapter, it gives you all the basic tools to build your own classifier.

As an aside, since you mentioned Twitter user names, I would also suggest using a normalizer as most names could contain just letters. For example instead of "Tom", a user name could also be "T0m". Perhaps you are already doing this, which in case you are, I am sorry for repeating it again.